# Rigol Ultrascope remote via Internet

Tags: oscilloscope, remote

Has anyone had any success in using the Rigol Ultrascope software to control a scope remotely via Internet - ie not just on a local LAN?
It works fine on the local LAN and apparently uses port 5555. I set up port forwarding of this port in my modem to the scope, but could not get Ultrascope to work using my public IP address. I am wondering if Ultrascope also uses another port for something?

I was able to use Putty to connect to the scope from outside the LAN in command line mode.

My object is to be able to share the scope screen (and controls) with a colleague at a different location while discussing a problem.

I am using a DS4014, but Ultrascope is the same for all models I think.

While I'm asking, is there any other/better software for remoting a Rigol scope?

Comment: Likely the protocol itself uses the hosts IP address

Comment: PlasmaHH I'm not sure what you mean. You get to enter the IP address of the scope into UltraScope - it just doesn't work when the address is not on the local LAN.

Comment: Try making the scope a DMZ, thus all requests to your public IP will be forwarded to the scope. If this does not work, then plasma is probably correct.

Comment: You could use [remote desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) to connect to a PC on your LAN and run Ultrascope on that.

Comment: If the protocol that is used to talk to the scope transmits the lan IP and tries to use that instead it fails. Try using wireshark to figure out what it does

Comment: Does Labview use more convential drivers??  https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Using-RIGOL-1054z-with-Labview-Beginner/td-p/3780124  I believe the scopes will work with VISA drivers

Answer (score 3):

I have had success using the Rigol TCP/IP.  There are three choices documented on page 14-3 of the [Users Guide](https://www.batronix.com/pdf/Rigol/UserGuide/MSO4000_DS4000_UserGuide_EN.pdf).  The one to avoid is "Auto IP".  This will give you and address on the 169.254 which is not routed.  I have used both DHCP and Manual, but I like Manual best, because the Rigol keeps its configuration.
If you use manual remember to set subnet mask and gateway so that packets will be routed.

Now the hard part begins.  You need to map a TCP port through your NAT router or firewall.  Found this in another post, "SCPI Sockets TCP 5025 Communication with the instrument Use this port to open a raw TCP/IP connection to send raw SCPI commands to the instrument".  Since you know how to use Wireshark, I suggest you get things working on a local connection first and sniff the port.

All of this is a lot of work.  You might consider a service that allows you to upload instrument data via HTTPS.  You run client software on your laptop or other computer that acts as a gateway between SCPI (communicates with oscilloscope) and HTTPS.

The services I know of are [Initial State](https://www.initialstate.com/waveforms/) and [GradientOne](https://www.gradientone.com/).  GradientOne has a "Live Remote Oscilloscope Waveform Capture" that let's you control an Oscilloscope remotely.  The scope happens to be a Rigol, but I think any oscilloscope that supports SCPI commands over VXI-11 would work.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some digging with Wireshark and it appears the answer to my question is it can't be done. The Rigol Ultrascope and Ultraview software does not simply establish a simple TCP connection from the PC to the scope at a given IP address. There are a whole lot of broadcast messages etc for finding instruments on the LAN and set up messages that uses a bunch of different ports.

This is fine for auto location of instruments on a local LAN but it is a pity they don't also provide a means of simply entering an IP address (anywhere on the net).

Answer (score 0):

Rigol scopes support VISA -- https://rigol.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2268969-remote-communication-using-visa  -- and VISA can use TCP/IP

Any app that lets you control VISA instruments should do fine.  NI-VISA or pyVISA, for example. https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: I suspect you may be confusing things a little - VISA can speak TCP/IP *to instruments which want to talk it* (it can also do serial, GPIB, etc), but the problem is that the *scope* apparently doesn't want to interact with machines not on the local network.   To the extent that VISA is unique, it's not in how it communicates with the instrument, but rather in abstracting that and providing an API for other PC software.  What would actually be needed would be a VPN or a local machine to function as a proxy and relay messages or simply be a remote desktop target.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Chris, the Rigol link specifically says all instruments of theirs post 2010 can use TCP/IP

Comment: VISA is just a PC-side abstraction library.  If the comment that putty from outside worked indicates that the basic TCP/IP coms are working and the issues were unique to something else that Utrascope does in the way of zeroconf address browsing or similar, then it might work.  But it would still require *client* software that has knowledge of the what the scope model in question can do - VISA is just a communication library.  I found an open source program for my Rigol that worked via USB-TMC (would be easy to modify for TCP) but again the question is **support for the particular scope**